# Unicode text gets corrupted while converting from xml data type to nvarchar in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql-server, xml, unicode

In our database the information about translations are stored in a XML column and we extract it using `.value()` function of `xml` datatype. We use `nvarchar(100)` as target data type, but the values get corrupted after conversion.

Here is the sample code:

```
DECLARE @x Xml
SET @x =
'<TRANSLATIONS>
    <TRANSLATION Lang="de">Probenname</TRANSLATION>
    <TRANSLATION Lang="pt">Tipo da Amostra</TRANSLATION>
    <TRANSLATION Lang="ru">Вид пробы</TRANSLATION>
    <TRANSLATION Lang="eo">Testaĵnomo</TRANSLATION>
</TRANSLATIONS>'

SELECT TR.lentry.value('@Lang','varchar(2)') AS Lang,
       TR.lentry.value('.','nvarchar(100)') AS Text    
FROM @x.nodes('/TRANSLATIONS/TRANSLATION') AS TR(lentry)
```

Here is the output we get:

```
Lang Text
---- ----------
de   Probenname
pt   Tipo da Amostra
ru   ??? ?????
eo   Testajnomo
```

As one might see, the Cyrillic entry is completely mingled whereas the Esperanto entry has lost its diacritic sign.

Any idea how one can repair it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your xml constant is varchar so the data is lost before the parse. Add the N prefix to make it varchar

```
DECLARE @x Xml

-- broke
SET @x =
'<TRANSLATIONS>
    <TRANSLATION Lang="de">Probenname</TRANSLATION>
    <TRANSLATION Lang="pt">Tipo da Amostra</TRANSLATION>
    <TRANSLATION Lang="ru">Вид пробы</TRANSLATION>
    <TRANSLATION Lang="eo">Testaĵnomo</TRANSLATION>
</TRANSLATIONS>';
SELECT @x;

-- fixed
SET @x =
N'<TRANSLATIONS>
    <TRANSLATION Lang="de">Probenname</TRANSLATION>
    <TRANSLATION Lang="pt">Tipo da Amostra</TRANSLATION>
    <TRANSLATION Lang="ru">Вид пробы</TRANSLATION>
    <TRANSLATION Lang="eo">Testaĵnomo</TRANSLATION>
</TRANSLATIONS>';
SELECT @x;

SELECT TR.lentry.value('@Lang','varchar(2)') AS Lang,
       TR.lentry.value('.','nvarchar(100)') AS Text    
FROM @x.nodes('/TRANSLATIONS/TRANSLATION') AS TR(lentry);
```